# How to change the initializer of a Variable (AttributeError: can't set attribute)?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a `Variable` defined somewhere in the code, and I don't have control over its creation parameters. I want to change its initializer after it has been instanciated. However the straightforward approach doesn't work:

```
import tensorflow as tf

foo = tf.get_variable('foo', shape=(), initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0))
foo.initializer = tf.initializers.constant(1)
# AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Why is that, and what is the work-around?

I use TF 1.14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns our that you can change the initializer via the protected `Variable._initializer_op` member.

However the initializer op is the concrete operator that `assign`s a value to the `Variable` — it is not an `tf.keras.initializer.Initializer` or one of its children that one provides as the `initializer` argument of `Variable`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

foo = tf.get_variable('foo', shape=(), initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0))
foo._initializer_op = foo.assign(tf.ones_like(foo))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  print(foo.eval())
  # 1.0
```

This inconsistency in the API could be one of the reasons why the `_initializer_op` is a protected member rather than a public one.